# Equivalent condition for $\mu$-measurability

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal{R}$ a ring of subsets of $X$ and $\mu : \mathcal{R} \to [0, \infty]$ a countably additive measure. Denote by $\mu^* : \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0, \infty]$ the induced outer measure defined by $\mu^*(E) := \inf \{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n) \mid A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n, A_n \in \mathcal{R} \}$ with $\inf(\emptyset) := \infty$ (for the case that $A$ cannot be covered by a countable collection of sets in $\mathcal{R}$).

A set $E \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ is called $\mu^*$-measurable if
$$\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c) \quad \textrm{for all } A \in \mathcal{P}(X).$$

I want to prove that it is in fact sufficient to check this splitting property for all sets $A \in \mathcal{R}$ with $\mu(A) < \infty$.

In case $\mathcal{R}$ is an algebra, this fact is mentioned in [D. Maharam, "From finite to countable additivity" (1987), p. 273], but the proof is based on a topological characterization of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{R}^\mu$ of $\mu$-measurable sets: $\mu$ induces a canonical topology on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ under which  $\mathcal{R}^\mu = \overline{\mathcal{R}}$ (closure of $\mathcal{R}$ in $\mathcal{P}(X)$). I am searching for a more direct proof and also for the case that $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align*}
\mu^{\ast}(A)=\inf\left\{\sum\mu(A_{n}): A\subseteq\bigcup A_{n}, A_{n}\in\mathcal{R},\mu(A_{n})<\infty\right\}.
\end{align*}
Now given $A,E\in\mathcal{P}(X)$, $A\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup A_{n}$ with $A_{n}\in\mathcal{R}$, $\mu(A_{n})<\infty$, 
\begin{align*}
\sum\mu(A_{n})&=\sum\mu^{\ast}(A_{n}\cap E)+\sum\mu^{\ast}(A_{n}\cap E^{c})\\
&\geq\mu^{\ast}\left(\bigcup(A_{n}\cap E)\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(\bigcup(A_{n}\cap E^{c})\right)\\
&=\mu^{\ast}\left(\left(\bigcup A_{n}\right)\cap E\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(\left(\bigcup A_{n}\right)\cap E^{c}\right)\\
&\geq\mu^{\ast}(A\cap E)+\mu^{\ast}(A\cap E^{c}),
\end{align*}
so $\mu^{\ast}(A)\geq\mu^{\ast}(A\cap E)+\mu^{\ast}(A\cap E^{c})$.