# Universal characterization of $\mu^*$-measurable sets / Galois connection between measures and outer measures?

Tags: measure-theory, category-theory

1. Let $X$ be a set and $\mu : \mathcal{R} \to [0, \infty]$ a measure on a ring of sets $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. Denote by $\mu^* : \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0, \infty]$ the induced outer measure and by $\mathcal{R}^\mu$ the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu$-measurable sets. With [this characterization of $\mu$-measurability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386836/equivalent-condition-for-mu-measurability/3386865#3386865) it follows that $\mathcal{R}^\mu$ is the largest ring on which $\mu^*$ is finitely additive (hence countably additive). This provides a canonical characterization of $\mathcal{R}^\mu$ (in universal terms).

Proof: Let $\mathcal{R}' \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ be a ring with $\mathcal{R}^\mu \subseteq \mathcal{R}'$ such that $\mu^* : \mathcal{R}' \to [0, \infty]$ is finitely additive. Let $E \in \mathcal{R}'$. Then for all $A \in \mathcal{R}$ it follows from $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{R}'$ that $A \cap E \in \mathcal{R}'$ and $A \cap E^c = A \setminus E \in \mathcal{R}'$ and therefore $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*((A \cap E) \cup (A \cap E^c)) = \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c)$ by finite additive of $\mu^*$ on $\mathcal{R}'$.
Since this is true for all $A \in \mathcal{R}$ it follows that $E \in \mathcal{R}^\mu$.

Now let $\eta$ be an arbitrary outer measure on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (not necessarily induced by a measure). Then we can also define $\mathcal{R}^{\eta}$ as the set of $\eta$-measurable sets. Then $\mathcal{R}^\eta$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\eta$ on $\mathcal{R}^\eta$ is countably additive. I was wondering whether $\mathcal{R}^\eta$ is the largest ring on which $\eta$ is finitely additive. The issue here is that $\eta$-measurable sets lack the simpler characterization used above for induced outer measures.

2. From a measure $\mu$ we can induce an outer measure $\mu^*$ and from an outer measure $\eta$ we can induce a complete measure by restriction to $\mathcal{R}^\eta$. We can iterate these mappings, but they give nothing new. This looks like a Galois connection. For a fixed set $X$, denote by $\mathbf{M}_X$ the set of measures $\mu : \mathcal{R} \to [0, \infty]$ on rings $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ and by $\mathbf{O}_X$ the set of outer measures $\eta : \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0, \infty]$. Then inducing an outer measure and restricting to a complete measure gives mappings $i : \mathbf{M}_X \to \mathbf{O}_X$ and $r : \mathbf{O}_X \to \mathbf{M}_X$. Then $iri = i$ and $rir = r$. The fixed points are then complete measures and induced outer measures. Is there some more intrinsic characterization of the induced outer measures (similar to completeness for measures)?

**Edit**: I think a drawback to 1. is that the largest ring / algebra / $\sigma$-algebra satisfying some property need not exist in general.
Example: Let $X = \{ a, b \}$, $a \neq b$ and $\eta : \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0, \infty]$ be defined by $\eta(\emptyset) = 0$, $\eta(\{ a \}) = 1 = \eta( \{ b \} )$ and $\eta(X) = \frac{3}{2}$ as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742074/outer-measure-and-caratheodorys-criterion). Then $\eta$ is an outer measure, $\eta$ is not finitely additive on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, but $\eta$ is finitely additive on all rings strictly contained in $\mathcal{P}(X)$, e.g. on $\{ \emptyset, \{ a \}, X \}$, on $\{ \emptyset, \{ b \}, X \}$ and of course on $\mathcal{R}^\eta = \{ \emptyset, X \}$. The collection of these rings does not possess a largest element.

One can possibly also construct counterexamples that show that there need not exist a largest algebra / $\sigma$-algebra on which $\mu^*$ is finitely additive. So we can rephrase the question 1.: *Is there some "universal characterization" of Caratheodory $\mu^*$-measurability?*

**Edit**: For 2., I got to know, that there is the concept of regularity for outer measures. An outer measure $\mu^*$ is regular if every set $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ can be covered by a $\mu^*$-measurable set $E \supseteq A$ with same outer measure $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(E)$ - this is an intrinsic characterization. Every induced outer measure is regular. I think, the fixed points of the Galois connection on the outer measures side should be the regular outer measures.